# Can I implement a SaaS infrastructure with Juju?

Tags: juju

My aim is to implement software as a service using cloud computing. Can we use Juju for implementation of Software as a service? We can deploy MySQL and Wordpress using Juju. But I want to install other applications (e.g matlab etc) on my server and want to give access for those applications to client.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this.

You can use Juju as a "build-your-own SaaS", deploy Matlab and expose it to people as a SaaS.

Cornell University's [Red Cloud](http://www.cac.cornell.edu/redcloud/) seems to be similar to what you want to deploy. Mathworks also has a [similar looking service](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-ec2.html) for EC2.

The first step would be charming up Matlab and deploying it in the same way you would have deployed MySQL and WordPress.

That's only the first step --- deploying it is still not SaaS, there's a bunch of things you'd need to build around it. Things like billing, customer service, security,

Juju can certainly help get you there (especially when it comes to horizontal scaling and setting up a multitenant architecture) but there are many moving parts to providing Software as a Service, there's probably an entire suite of tools that take part in this.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Jorge just said, we are working on an "anything-as-a-service" solution called JXaaS. The idea is that if you have a Matlab charm, then you can offer it as a MathLab-as-a-Service solution either by automatically spinning up a new instance per tenant or if the charm and underlying software supports it via a single multi-tenant platform. The work is still very early stage but since it is on Github you might want to take a look and perhaps even contribute:
https://github.com/jxaas/jxaas

Comment: Can a payment service be attached to Juju?